# DateTime difference + Convert days to hours

Tags: php

I want to display how much time is remaining between the current time and a future time in hours:minutes:seconds (converts days into hours).

```
# Current time.
$current_datetime=new DateTime();
# Time in future.
$future_time=new DateTime('2015-09-30 05:59:38');
# Get difference.
$interval=$current_datetime->diff($future_time);
# Format time (this does not convert days to hours).
//$duration=$interval->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

After that I thought I could do:

```
$duration=sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $interval->days * 24 + $interval->H, $interval->i, $interval->s);
```

But that's not working properly. It's displaying `00:27:27`. The minutes and seconds are correct but it's showing 00 for hours.

Comment: Can you show what you're expected output is?

Comment: Have you tried $interval->h instead of $interval->H in your second approach? Property names are case sensitive in PHP.

Comment: check like this for hour ($interval->days * 24) + ($interval->H) . Just a suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

PHP's `DateInterval` class's hours component is named `h` not `H` (remember PHP is case-sensitive).

Comment: Wow, totally missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$start_date = new DateTime('older date');
$end_date = new DateTime('newer date');
$interval = $start_date->diff($end_date);//find the date difference
$diff = $interval->format('%h')+($interval->format('%d')*24)+($interval->format('%m')*28*24)+($interval->format('%y')*365*28*24);
```

//convert the difference all into hours only
by multiplying day by 24, months by 28 and 24, years by 365 and 28 and 24 the add all together to get the closest approximate hour difference.

Answer (score -1):

Get Current timestamp and future date timestamp and take it's difference.

Once you get a difference. you can manipulate difference and convert it into hours minutes and seconds.

```
$diff = $future_timestamp - time();
$hours = $diff % 3600;
$minutes = ($diff - ($hours*3600)) % 60;
$seconds = $diff - (($hours*3600) + ($minutes*60));
```

Comment: Note the "mathematical" method is discourage because it's not safe calc the difference when there are daylight savings or other time changes in place.